# How to pass pointer to pointer (**) in JNA?

Tags: java-native-interface, jna

I have function in  native code `void clang_tokenize(CXTranslationUnit TU, CXSourceRange Range, CXToken **Tokens, unsigned *NumTokens);`

The function is going to return allocated array of tokens in `**Tokens` and tokens count in `*NumTokens`. I've generated structs using jnaerator, so they are ready. how can i write function signature in java (pointer to pointer is main difficulty)? For unsigned* i have `IntByReference` in JNA. Should i use PointerByReference? Give me example please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `CXToken` is a struct, and the called function is returning an array allocated by the callee:

```
PointerByReference pref = new PointerByReference();
IntByReference iref = new IntByReference();

clang_tokenize(tu, range, pref, iref);
CXToken token = new CXToken(pref.getValue());
CXToken[] tokens = (CXToken[])token.toArray(iref.getValue());
```

Comment: In the last line i'm getting an error: 

    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Bounds exceeds available space : size=8, offset=48
 at com.sun.jna.Memory.boundsCheck(Memory.java:197)
 at com.sun.jna.Memory$SharedMemory.boundsCheck(Memory.java:73)
 at com.sun.jna.Memory.share(Memory.java:115)
 at com.sun.jna.Structure.toArray(Structure.java:1261)
 at com.sun.jna.Structure.toArray(Structure.java:1280)

Comment: toke.size() is not equal to iref.getValue() for some reason, but it should be IMHO. I understand that the value is returned from Clang and it can be wrong, but i think it's tested enough..

Comment: oh, pref.size() is size of token pointer not array of tokens. but why am i getting an exception?

Comment: sorry, i've passed

    (CXToken[])token.toArray(getPointer());

instead of

    (CXToken[])token.toArray(iref.getValue());